# How to check if text file for palindromes without it being case sensitive

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is my current code. It works but it doesn't work with uppercase letters in the word, so Anna wont work. Any suggestions on how to ignore case sensitivity?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("mytext.txt");

    string line = "";

    do
    {

        std::stack<char>
            s(std::stack<char>::container_type(line.begin(), line.end()));
        std::queue<char>
            q(std::queue<char>::container_type(line.begin(), line.end()));

        while (!s.empty() && s.top() == q.front())
        {
            s.pop();
            q.pop();
        }

        if (s.empty()) std::cout << line << " The string is a palindrome" << std::endl;
    } while (getline(infile, line));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pro tip: `std::deque` can be used if you want to efficiently remove elements from both ends, so you don't need two copies of the line.

Comment: You should upvote the answers and decide which one you accept (the checkmark)

Comment: there's no even need for a stack or queue. Just iterate with a simple loop

Answer (score 1):

Create a pivot string with all lower case letters. Use std::tolower to convert your string

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
std::string str_tolower(std::string s) {
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), 
               [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); } 
              );
return s;
}
```

And then check  for palindromes.

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly im suppose to put something like this, but it's just spitting out errors like has no member begin, end, begin, and others. I placed it between the queue and the palindrome check.

Comment: It is a sample function that converts a string to lower case. You should adjust your code using this idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing that has to change is the comparison operation. You are comparing the two chars directly. What you would have to do is convert them to upper or to lower case first, before comparing.

**To lower**

```
while (!s.empty() && std::tolower(s.top()) == std::tolower(q.front()))
{
   s.pop();
   q.pop();
}
```

**To upper**

```
while (!s.empty() && std::toupper(s.top()) == std::toupper(q.front()))
{
   s.pop();
   q.pop();
}
```

**With Ascii codes**

If you want to be fancy, you could also try to do this by converting to the ascii representation, and doing `-65` or `-97` respectively.

```
int s_top = (int(s.top()) < 97) ? int(s.top()) - 65 : int(s.top()) - 97;
int q_front = (int(q.front()) < 97) ? int(q.front()) - 65 : int(q.front()) - 97;
while (!s.empty() && s_top == q_front)
{
   s.pop();
   q.pop();
   s_top = (int(s.top()) < 97) ? int(s.top()) - 65 : int(s.top()) - 97;
   q_front = (int(q.front()) < 97) ? int(q.front()) - 65 : int(q.front()) - 97; 
}
```

97 stands for "a" in ASCII and 65 stands for "A".

Answer (score 0):

You want to read a file line by line. For each line you want to check, if a line is a palindrome. An additional constraint is that the check should be done case insensitive. For one of the may possible soultions we could do the following

1. Open the file, check, if it could be opened
2. Read all lines in the file
3. Create a copy of a the line, with all lowercase characters
4. Check, if the copy of the line with all lowercase characters is a palindrome
5. Print the original line as result

Additional explanation for creating a lowercase file:

We use a std algorithm from the STL: `std::transform`. With that, we iterate over each character in the string and convert it to lowercase with the build-in function `tolower`

Detecting a palindrome is an easy task, we just compare the string with its reversed version. So, we compare the lowercase string with a temporary `std::string` constructed with the "range" constructor. And for the "range", we do not use the standard `begin()`and `end()` iterators, but the reverse versions `std::rbegin()` and `std::rend()`. This is the standard approach and very simple.

If we could find a palindrome, the we print out the original line.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    // Open the file
    std::ifstream file("mytext.txt");

    // If the file could be opened . . .
    if (file) {

        // Read all lines
        std::string line{};
        while (std::getline(file, line)) {

            // Derive a string with lowercase characters from read line
            std::string lcLine(line.size(),'\0');
            // Transform to lowercase
            std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), lcLine.begin(), ::tolower);

            // Check, if we have a palindrome
            if (lcLine == std::string(lcLine.rbegin(), lcLine.rend())) {

                // Show the line with a palindrome
                std::cout << "Found a palindrome in:   " << line << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```